# Are you printing an additional character at the beginning of each line? - main error left aligned pyramid

Tags: python, cs50

I'm currently at pset6 from cs50, [mario-less](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/mario/less/). My code compiles and prints the left aligned pyramid as the problem asks, but when I do a check50, most of them fail. What is the problem?

```
from cs50 import get_int

# Ask user for input
n = get_int("Height: ")

# While loop to check condition
while n < 1 or n > 8:
    print("Invalid number ")
    n = get_int("Enter another number: ")

# One for loop to prin left sided piramid
for j in range(1, n + 1):
    spaces = n - j + 1
    print(" " * spaces + "#" * j)
```

Comment: What is get_int? Is this what you need to implement? Do you have  a start?

Comment: yes, it specifies in description to import get_int function from cs50 library

Comment: Is this for a class? What does it need to do? We dont have access to cs50?

Comment: i`m currently doing the cs50x course from Harvard for free and i`m on week 6, where I have to print a left sided piramid out of hashes. My code seems to work in their web visual studio, but it doesnt pass the test ccheck. i`m going to sleep for now, i`m beat. thanks for the interest

Comment: @stefanp You're using the backtick character `\`` for your apostrophe instead of `'` which is used for code in markdown. That's why your text is showing up weird.

Comment: @daemon CS50 is a freely-available harvard course. This specific problem is [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/mario/less/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it currently stands, for `n == 5` your code will print:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
```

However, we want to avoid that extra space at the start of every line and get:

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

So just reduce the number of spaces you are adding by 1:

```py
# One for loop to print left sided pyramid
for j in range(1, n + 1):
    spaces = n - j
    print(" " * spaces + "#" * j)
```

Comment: hah, thanks dude. I was super tired and I missed that. you saved me a lot of time with an awesome simple explanation. Thanks - sorry, I don`t have reputation 15 yet for vote

Answer (score 1):

I did cs50 a while ago and my answer was something like yours (we probably based it on the C code we did prior). But thinking about it now, another way to do this with the help of fstrings would be like this:

```
n = int(input('height: ')
c = 1
for i in range(n):
    print(f'{" "*(n-1)}{"#"*c}')
    n -= 1
    c += 1
```